# How to place a two-row limit expression below the integral sign?

Tags: math-mode, equations

How do I write multiple lines beneath the integral sign?

MWE:

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{amsmath}

 \begin{document}

 \begin{equation}
 \int \mathcal{D}\phi(x)=
 \int \mathcal{D}\phi_1(\textbf{x})
 \int \mathcal{D}\phi_2(\textbf{x})
 \int_{\phi(x^0_1,\textbf{x})=\phi_1(\textbf{x}),
     \phi(x^0_2,\textbf{x})=\phi_2(\textbf{x})}
     \mathcal{D}\phi(x)
 \end{equation}

 \end{document}
```

I would like the output to be as below (highlighted):

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a variant on @Bernard's [third equation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/453969/5001), using `\smashoperator[r]{...}` instead of `\smashoperator{...}`.

Note that I've reduced the distance between the `\int` and `\mathcal{D}` terms slightly, by inserting `\!` ("negative thinspace") directives. I've also replaced `\textbf{x}` with `\mathbf{x}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for \smashoperator macro
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
 \int\! \mathcal{D}\phi(x)=
 \int\! \mathcal{D}\phi_1(\mathbf{x})
 \int\! \mathcal{D}\phi_2(\mathbf{x})
 \smashoperator[r]{\int\limits_{\substack{%
    \phi(x^0_1,\mathbf{x})=\phi_1(\mathbf{x}),\\
    \phi(x^0_2,\mathbf{x})=\phi_2(\mathbf{x})\hfill}}}
      \! \mathcal{D}\phi(x)
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

My proposal is to back up a little, but not too much as with `\smashoperator`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\int \mathcal{D}\phi(x)=
\int \mathcal{D}\phi_1(\mathbf{x})
\int \mathcal{D}\phi_2(\mathbf{x})
\int\limits_{\scriptscriptstyle\mspace{-12mu}
             \begin{subarray}{l}
             \phi(x^0_1,\mathbf{x})=\phi_1(\mathbf{x}),\\
             \phi(x^0_2,\mathbf{x})=\phi_2(\mathbf{x})
             \end{subarray}\mspace{-24mu}}
    \mathcal{D}\phi(x)
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

The important part is `\int\limits` so the condition is placed below the integral sign. The `subarray` environment is similar to `\substack`, but it takes an argument for the alignment of the rows.

[image]

Comment: I get that you introduced those `mspace` for centering sake, but why is that you need them both negative and set to `-12mu` and `-24mu`, respectively?

Comment: @Fitzcarraldo I don't remember the details of my experiment, but the idea is to keep into account the width of the integral sign. They're negative because I wanted the subscript to look less wide than it actually is, so the parts at right and left of it slighly overlap.

Answer (score 6):

In  my opinion, it looks nicer at the bottom right side of the integral. Anyway, here are 3 possibilies:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\int\mathcal{D}\phi(x)=\int \mathcal{D}\phi_1(\textbf{x}) \int \mathcal{D}\phi_2(\textbf{x}) \int_{\substack{\phi(x^0_1,\textbf{x})=\phi_1(\textbf{x}),\\ \phi(x^0_2,\textbf{x})=\phi_2(\textbf{x})\strut}} \mathcal{D}\phi(x) 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\int\mathcal{D}\phi(x)=\int \mathcal{D}\phi_1(\textbf{x}) \int \mathcal{D}\phi_2(\textbf{x}) \int_{\mathrlap{\substack{\mathstrut\\\phi(x^0_1,\textbf{x})=\phi_1(\textbf{x}),\\ \phi(x^0_2,\textbf{x})=\phi_2(\textbf{x})\strut}}}\; \mathcal{D}\phi(x)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\int\mathcal{D}\phi(x)=\int \mathcal{D}\phi_1(\textbf{x}) \int \mathcal{D}\phi_2(\textbf{x}) \smashoperator{ \int_{\substack{\phi(x^0_1,\textbf{x})=\phi_1(\textbf{x}),\\ \phi(x^0_2,\textbf{x})=\phi_2(\textbf{x})\strut}}} \mathcal{D}\phi(x)
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

By making use of the `substack` command (requires the `amsmath` package):

```
\underset{\substack{\phi(x_1^0,x) = \phi_1(x) \\ \phi(x_2^0,x)= \phi_2(x)}}{\int}
```

Some additional pointers:

1. Since you're using `\mathcal{D}` fairly often, I would advise declaring a new command with `\newcommand{\D}{\ensuremath{\mathcal{D}}}`. Then you can simply use `\D` every time you need it. Makes your code far more readable.
2. Put `\tag{9.16}` at the end of the line to tag the equation as (9.16), as per the image.
3. Your code for `\phi(x^0_2,\textbf{x})` produces parentheses which are not big enough. You should instead use `\left( \right)` to have them correctly sized.
4. You should not use `\textbf{x}` to indicate the vector `x`. Instead, use `\vec{x}` (which puts an arrow above the `x`). If you want to change the output of `\vec{x}` to bold text instead, use `\renewcommand\vec{\mathbf}`.

All these suggestions plus the original answer are incorporated here:

```
\newcommand{\D}{\ensuremath{\mathcal{D}}}
\renewcommand\vec{\mathbf}

\begin{equation} 
\int\D\phi(x)=
\int \D\phi_1(\vec{x}) 
\int \D\phi_2(\vec{x}) 
\int\limits_{\substack{\phi\left(x_1^0,\vec{x}\right) = \phi_1(\vec{x}) \\ \phi\left(x_2^0,\vec{x}\right)= \phi_2(\vec{x})}} \D\phi(x) \tag{9.16}
\end{equation}
```

This gives the desired output:

[image]

Comment: @campa I kind of agree re the brackets, but I'll leave it to OP's tastes. As for `\textbf`, I agree that it's better to redefine the `\vec` command instead; I'll edit that into my answer in a while.

Comment: @jowadulkader I have edited my answer to reflect campa's comment about vectors. Could you please upvote the answer (rather than just accept it)? Thank you!

Comment: `\underset`? Oh, no!

Comment: I believe it's far more idiomatic to write `\int\limits_{...}` than `\underset{...}{\int}`.

Comment: I don't think it's correct to claim that the some of the parentheses in the terms below the `\int` symbol have to be enlarged. The basic size does just fine. And, it is *not* necessary to switch from an `equation` environment to an `equation*` environment in order to use `\tag`. That said, I don't think that reproducing a specific equation number is part of the OP's stated objectives.